# Should we maintain a list of open source repositories that users can upload/contribute or download from?

Tags: discussion

It makes sense to me at least that there should be a list of useful repositories that users can download code from and maybe contribute to. This isn't a wish to enforce policy but that having a list on this site in my mind would be a useful bit of information.

Again this doesn't fit the normal SO Q&A format so I would protect this as a wiki or put it here perhaps?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point? What code? Code specific to the RPi?

Comment: yes, drivers, pet projects and libraries for talking to other devices etc..

Comment: How do you stop this from simply being self-advertisment?

Comment: I was thinking more of official repositories and useful libraries not a free for all for people to promote their own code

Answer (score -1):

This is a great idea. I would just write a generic question and then add the answer as community wiki so anyone can contribute to it.